# Connecting to Active Directory

Tags: powershell-2.0

I have the following script from a book. When I try to run this, I get nothing output to the screen.

```
$objADSI = [adsi]""
$domain = $objADSI.distinguishedname

$userContainer = [adsi]("LDAP://cn=users," + $domain)

foreach($child in $userContainer) {
    Write-Host $child.samaccountname
}
```

If I `echo` `$userContainer`, I get:

```
distinguishedName : {CN=Users,DC=company,DC=co,DC=uk}
Path              : LDAP://cn=users,DC=company,DC=co,DC=uk
```

Do I need to run winrm quickconfig on the Active Directory server? The Active Directory server is running Windows Server 2003 standard edition. Or am I getting nothing returned for some other reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your foreach like this:

```
foreach($child in $userContainer.children)
```